# Problema no Xampp NetStat TCP service stopped

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp

This problem happened 2 days ago, I tried to solve it, without solution. I went to sleep, the other day I woke up, I had solved myself. Every time I turn on xampp's apache, it randomizes the ports, then shuts off Apache itself and gives the NetStat TCP service stopped error message. Please restart the control panel. Returned -1073741823
I'm using Google Cloud Server, and for a couple of weeks that problem did not happen.

[xampp error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fapgv.png)
[netstat tcp service stopped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gljtK.png)

Someone how to solve? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall the xamp server , restart the system and install again

Comment: I did this several times, but without success

Answer (score 0):

go to controlPanel->windowsFirewall->allow a program or feature through windows firewall

now scroll down and see if your xamp is not in list then click on "allow another program" and from list add "xamp control panel" and check home/work private and you done............!!!!!!!!!!!!